# My first SOLID re-factoring

Tags: c#, solid

I am trying to make use of [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) for the first time. I am re-factoring a File class that stores file information and makes file operations available.
This class is then inherited to specific file types to make available methods for that type.

I have started with SRP and have tried to make a `FileWriter` and `FileReader` abstract class to read and write from different resources. Some include:

- File System
- Streams
- Database
- Other undefined services (`SOAP`, `REST`??).

I am happy to say that the file data is handled by a byte array, but I am not sure how to handle the file path/uid for a resource.

Here is what I have...

```
public abstract class EFileReader
{
    event EventHandler<IEFileEventArgs> ReadThreadedComplete;
    public abstract byte[] Read(object source);
    public abstract async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(object source);
    public abstract void ReadThreaded(object source);
    protected virtual void OnFileRead(IEFileEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<IEFileEventArgs> handler = this.ReadThreadedComplete;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I could cast the object as the required type in implementation.
Alternatively it could be a generic type somehow specified in implementation (not sure how).

```
public abstract class EFileReader<T>
{
    event EventHandler<IEFileEventArgs> ReadThreadedComplete;
    public abstract byte[] Read(T source);
    public abstract async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(T source);
    public abstract void ReadThreaded(T source);
    protected virtual void OnFileRead(IEFileEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<IEFileEventArgs> handler = this.ReadThreadedComplete;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

...Or maybe there is some abstraction of the source I can write to accommodate the various possible use cases.
I guess I could make it take an abstract `FileResource` class that exposes a stream.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Shouldn't there be some sort of type constraint on T? Maybe you could defer that the the implementations of `EFileReader`...

Comment: Yes, that makes me uneasy. In implementation I would define T.

Comment: Thinking about it more, so long as in the implementation T is defined or constrained a generic seems okay.

Comment: For DIP on a constructor passing the abstracted FileReader I need to make use of T in the class definition. This has a code smell I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of creating [`System.IO.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) in the framework, was to be able to handle data from different types of sources.

You should just make your `source` parameter a `Stream` type.

Also, you say your class handles data from different sources (including streams). This effectively no longer makes it a `File` class, doesn't it?

Comment: It should be a file regardless of the storage medium or transport protocol. It had data, name, extension and mimetype.

Comment: Stream does sound like it would work.

Comment: If a stream is used abstraction of read and write seems pointless

Comment: Well, the framework already has `StreamReader`...

Comment: Hahaha. So my refactoring hasn't really changed anything yet.

Comment: I am going to hold out for something better for a little longer.